# What are the main differences between BIND9 and Bundy?

Tags: dns, debian, server, bind, bind9

What are the main differences between BIND9 and Bundy? Is Bundy secure to use? I real on their [website](http://bundy-dns.de/) that:

> The project is currently working on fixing up some loose ends in the
>   code inherited, clean the code, and to get the initial infrastructure
>   up and running to support the first Bundy release.

Is it buggy? Should I go with BIND9 or move to Bundy? I am running Debian Wheezy. If it is better than BIND9, how can I complete get rid of BIND9 and have no conflicts with Bundy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting in 2009, the Internet Software Consortium (ISC) developed a new software suite, initially called BIND10. With release version 1.2.0 the project was renamed Bundy to terminate ISC involvement in the project. [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIND)

Answer (score 4):

Bundy is a rewrite of the BIND DNS system that is designed for a lot more scalability and security than BIND9. It is more complex to configure than  BIND9 and includes much more modularity.

A BIND9 instance normally has the following service running:
Bind9/named

Bundy has the following services:
**bundy-auth** — Authoritative DNS server. This process serves DNS requests.
**bundy-cfgmgr** — Configuration manager. This process maintains all of the configuration for Bundy.
**bundy-cmdctl** — Command and control service. This process allows external control of the Bundy system.
**bundy-ddns** — Dynamic DNS update service. This process is used to handle incoming DNS update requests to allow granted clients to update zones for which Bundy is serving as a primary server.
**bundy-msgq** — Message bus daemon. This process coordinates communication between all of the other Bundy processes.
**bundy-resolver** — Recursive name server. This process handles incoming DNS queries and provides answers from its cache or by recursively doing remote lookups. (This is an experimental proof of concept.)
**bundy-sockcreator** — Socket creator daemon. This process creates sockets used by network-listening Bundy processes.
**bundy-stats** — Statistics collection daemon. This process collects and reports statistics data.
**bundy-stats-httpd** — HTTP server for statistics reporting. This process reports statistics data in XML format over HTTP.
**bundy-xfrin** — Incoming zone transfer service. This process is used to transfer a new copy of a zone into Bundy, when acting as a secondary server.
**bundy-xfrout** — Outgoing zone transfer service. This process is used to handle transfer requests to send a local zone to a remote secondary server.
**bundy-zonemgr**— Secondary zone manager. This process keeps track of timers and other necessary information for Bundy to act as a slave server.

Additionally, Bind9 still includes the DHCP server in it's installation. This feature is no longer in Bundy ([it's the one piece that the ISC held onto](https://www.isc.org/kea/))

https://ripe68.ripe.net/presentations/208-The_Decline_and_Fall_of_BIND_10.pdf